# split list data in each column of table

Tags: list, pyspark

I am facing issue while converting list data to Data frame(table).
I have data in list.(Input)

[['FWD,29052016:09:01,10.56', ' FWD,29052016:10:53,11.23', 'FWD,29052016:15:40,23.20'],
['SPOT,29052016:09:04,11.56', ' FWD,29052016:11:45,11.23', ' SPOT,29052016:12:30,23.20'],
['FWD,29052016:08:01,10.56', ' SPOT,29052016:12:30,11.23', ' FWD,29052016:13:20,23.20', ' FWD,29052016:14:340,56.00'], ['FWD,29052016:08:01,10.56', ' SPOT,29052016:12:30,11.23', ' FWD,29052016:13:20,23.20']]

Expected Output:(table format) looking in pyspark.

FWD     29052016:09:01  10.56
FWD     29052016:10:53  11.23
SPOT    29052016:09:04  11.56

I have tried but not working correctly.

## parallelize data

data1 = sc.parallelize(data)

## data_converted into map

data_converted = data1.map(lambda x: (x[0][2], x[1][1], x[2][1]))

## create table ( createDataFrame)

DF1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data_converted, schema)

getting result
DF1.show()

but getting result. that is not meeting my requirement.

Product_type| date| time

```
       D|   F|   F|
       O|   F|   S|
```

Comment: Hi @Praveen Saini, does your data naturally come in that format, or are you able to change it?

Comment: Hi @wade Pimenta I have a text file which have data in below format and i want to put data into table (separate by , and | ).                       FWD,29052016:09:01,10.56| FWD,29052016:10:53,11.23| FWD,29052016:15:40,23.20
SPOT,29052016:09:04,11.56| FWD,29052016:11:45,11.23| SPOT,29052016:12:30,23.20
FWD,29052016:08:01,10.56| SPOT,29052016:12:30,11.23| FWD,29052016:13:20,23.20| FWD,29052016:14:340,56.00
FWD,29052016:08:01,10.56| SPOT,29052016:12:30,11.23| FWD,29052016:13:20,23.20

Comment: Okay good to know, also, in the example above I see there is a "FWD,29052016:09:01,10.56| FWD,29052016:10:53,11.23| FWD,29052016:15:40,23.20 SPOT,29052016:09:04,11.56" where there is a "|" missing between the last FWD and SPOT messages. Is this a typo, or is a part of the data?

Comment: Hi @Wade Pimenta data is same manner which is present in first line there are (| and , ) separate. I want to load this data in table removing (, and |) . for more clarification . I need this data in below format. input data : FWD,29052016:09:01,10.56| FWD,29052016:10:53,11.23|  
 FWD,29052016:15:40,23.20  Output data: FWD 29052016:09:01 10.56
FWD 29052016:10:53 11.23
FWD 29052016:15:40 23.2 in tabular format

Comment: I have a solution for you to get the input data, as I believe you are describing into a spark dataframe, with columns "product", "date" and "time", however I make use of the "|" and "," characters as it is easier to set up the input data. Will this be ok, or do you absolutely need to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

*This answer assumes you only have access to pyspark within your environment. Further, this answer is based off of Spark 2.x and makes use of a SparkSession (from pyspark.sql import SparkSession), however, prior versions should achieve similar when using a SQLContext.*

This answers initializes the spark context in the following manner:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("my_app").getOrCreate()
```

Further, I am assuming your data is not dirty, and the original text file has every row separated by a "|". Where each row has a single string, where each value is separated by a "," within a .txt file.

Reading in the text file and splitting by the "|" delimiter to get it into a workable format

```
file = open("/example.txt", "r")
data = file.read().split('|')
```

We must then strip empty spaces and split the string by a "," so that we get a list of lists, where each inner list represents a three-column format that you expect:

```
data = [x.strip().split(',') for x in data]
```

This will look something like this (notice that every row has exactly one product, date and time value):

```
[['FWD', '29052016:09:01', '10.56'], ['FWD', '29052016:10:53', '11.23']]
```

If your data is a bit messy and you find that every "row" has more than 3 values, you will need to work on cleaning functions to get it into the correct format.

Now, we create the schema for the dataframe (Using strings for the purposes of this answer):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("product", StringType(), True),
        StructField("date", StringType(), True),
        StructField("time", StringType(), True)
    ]
)
```

And lastly, create the spark dataframe:

```
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

This results in the following, using the cleaned version of the example you gave me:

```
+-------+---------------+-----+
|product|           date| time|
+-------+---------------+-----+
|    FWD| 29052016:09:01|10.56|
|    FWD| 29052016:10:53|11.23|
|    FWD| 29052016:15:40|23.20|
|   SPOT| 29052016:09:04|11.56|
|    FWD| 29052016:11:45|11.23|
|   SPOT| 29052016:12:30|23.20|
|    FWD| 29052016:08:01|10.56|
|   SPOT| 29052016:12:30|11.23|
|    FWD| 29052016:13:20|23.20|
|    FWD|29052016:14:340|56.00|
|    FWD| 29052016:08:01|10.56|
|   SPOT| 29052016:12:30|11.23|
|    FWD| 29052016:13:20|23.20|
+-------+---------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks Wade. but there is one more issue. I tried this solution on databricks community edition using pyspark. While i reading file it is givig error  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/FileStore/tables/data/data.txt' but it is present. extremely sorry i am learner.

Comment: Hi @Wade, I have tried your solution on Pyspark Ubuntu 16.0 . Everything goes fine which you have mention above but while creating data Frame. Even i have given ( Lib : from pyspark.sql import SparkSession and  from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext) it giving error. NameError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-7bb4960f664a> in <module>
      1 dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
      2 #eventDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(eventCounts,('productID','date','price'))

Name Error: name 'spark' is not defined.

Comment: Hi @Praveen Saini! Looks like it is not giving you a spark context correctly, or your version is perhaps lower than 2.x, could you run "pyspark --version" in a terminal and tell me what it displays?

Also to confirm, did you solve the file not found problem? One more thing, can you also show me how you are creating your context? (IE: spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate())

Comment: Hi @Wade I run command on my terminal it is showing that system have Spark   version 2.4.0.

Comment: Kk, and how are you setting up the "spark" variable in your code? do you use: spark=SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() ?

Comment: Hi @Wade I used your solution, did some change as per my requirement and implemented and its's working fine now. Thanks for you kind help. ;)

Comment: Hi @PraveenSaini Glad I could help! If my answer solved your problem, would you kindly please mark this question as answered :)